# CSGO Low FPS Issue

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have recently installed CS:GO on my brother's laptop. Specifications  are as below:

Acer Aspire 5745PG
Core-i3, 4GB Ram, 2nd Generation, Nvidia GT-310M.

Game runs a little slow after playing up to 30 mins. On Start Game runs ok, but with fps 20-30. I could not understand why this is happening. Game runs smooth on 20-30 FPS. But after playing 30 min, the performance goes down.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're on a six year old laptop, with what was even then a lacklustre processor trying to play a CPU bound game. Other than the obvious (be sure other programs are closed, try lowering the resolution, etc) there not really anything to say except get a more suitable machine.

Comment: :( well i am trying different setting from different sources may be it works.

Comment: I don't have the minimum requirements at hand right now, but M-versions of graphical cards are nearly always unsupported. Technically no laptops are supported for any game anywhere, because to prevent the laptop from melting, strange and sometimes breaking changes are made to the M-versions to get the power consumption down.

Answer (score 2):

On top of your laptop not having the power to actually run it at higher fps, it's also overheating, which causes your cpu/gpu to throttle, which results in lowered fps.

There's a few things you can do to potentially alleviate the issue:

1. Clean the laptop from all the dust inside
2. Get a laptop fan mat (a mat with extra fans that you put your laptop on for extra cooling)
3. Both of the above